# Putting spaces in MySQL column aliases with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query the database using Eloquent and export the results in a spreadsheet. My current query is fine and the process works:

```
$clients = Client::
        select("ref as id", "title as salutation", "firstname", "surname as lastname", "tel as phone", "alttel as mobile", "email", "address1 as addressline1", "address2 as addressline2", "address3 as addressline3", "address4 as addressline4", "postcode as postalcode", "status")
        ->get();
```

I want to get field names as aliases with a space. I assumed I could do one of:

```
"firstname as first name"
"firstname as 'first name'"
"firstname as `first name`"
'firstname as "first name"'
```

Or something similar. However none of these work. The column name is just returned as something like `'first`. I have seen stuff elsewhere online to suggest this should be possible with MySQL - is it a particular Eloquent issue?

Is there some other way I need to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: I wonder what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need aliases with spaces anyway?

Comment: As I said, I am exporting the results in a spreadsheet. The field names become the header row names, and the business case requires fixed column names. It should be technically possible as MySQL can handle it. There are other ways to achieve the goal if it is impossible.

Comment: I'm sure there is prettier solution, any good package (for exporting data to a spreadsheet) should have method which sets field names.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes I can use a blade file export and set the names myself. Unless you know of a package or a way to use spaces with eloquent then you don't know?

Comment: I solved this by using `DB::raw`. Answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by using `DB::raw`. Here's the code if anyone else needs to know:

```
$clients = Client::
  ->select(DB::raw("ref as id, title as Salutation, firstname as 'First Name', surname as 'Last Name', tel as Phone, alttel as Mobile, email as Email, address1 as 'Address Line 1', address2 as 'Address Line 2', address3 as 'Address Line 3', address4 as 'Address Line 4', postcode as 'Postal Code', Status"))
  ->get();
```

This returns aliases with a space in them.

Comment: I think that is the solution if you still want to use those kind of column names yes, I'm not sure eloquent supports this kind of column name.

Answer (score 0):

The first option you listed works in Laravel 9:

```
DB::table('clients')->select('first_name as first name')->toSql()
```

returns:

```
select `first_name` as `first name` from `clients`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think laravel philosophy would be to use map()

```php
$clients = Client::select('ref', 'title', 'firstname', ...)
    ->get()
    ->map(function($client) {
        return [
            'ref' => $client->id,
            'firstname' => $client->firstname,
            'salutation' => $client->title,
        ];
    });
```

and even better, Higher order message:
define a formatAliased() method in your `Client` model

```php
public function formatAliased()
{
        return [
            'ref' => $this->id,
            'firstname' => $this->firstname,
            'salutation' => $this->title,
        ];
    });
}
```

then :
`$clients=Client::get()->map->formatAliased();`